# how to remove last string element unnecessary text if exists?

Tags: c#

I have a string array with 3 elements like below for example.

```
string[] stringarray1;
stringarray1 = new string[5]{ “Element 1\n”, “Element 2\n”, “Element 3\n”, “Element 4\n”, “Element 5\nblablablabla” };
```

Here i need to check last element in string array having unnecessary dynamic text "\nblablablabla", if exists i need to remove(till last of the dynamic text) and replace with "Element 5\n" in last element.

How can I do this?

Comment: Check if `stringarray1[stringarray1.Length - 1]` is "unnecessary" and if it is, replace it with `stringarray1[stringarray1.Length - 1] = "Element 5\n"`.

Comment: In example array has 5 elements, aways 3/5 elements? Always replaced text is "\nblablablabla"?

Comment: Sorry it's not always 3/5 elements. It's typo. Last element may contains some dynamic text at the end like "Element 5\nblabla" starts with "blabla.....", i have to remove this unnecessary text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringarray1.Length; i++)
{
    stringarray1[i] = stringarray1[i].Split("\n")[0] + "\n";
}
```

You can split string with respect to "\n" and take first of it and add "\n" again. This will remove unnessesary characters from your string that i understand.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking and replacing unnecessary text, you can replace what ever string you have with expected string

```
var lastIndex = stringarray1.Length -1;
stringarray1[lastIndex] = $"Element {lastIndex}\n";
```